# Deploy a Dockerized Symfony2 application on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: symfony, nginx, docker, environment-variables, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

**Important**: This question relates to an ancient version of both Symfony and Elastic Beanstalk Docker platforms. Environment variables are first-class citizens in Symfony 4+, so the problem described below no longer exists in the wild.

---

What is the correct way to deploy a multi-container docker symfony application?

I have following knowledge base and situation so far:

1. My docker-compose environment works locally and consists of nginx, php5-fpm, memcached, mysql and mailcatcher
2. I am using multi container EB application and the goal is to have a separate "test" and "production" environment running with separate configuration
3. I do already know I can't simply build the whole thing within EB and have to have built images already, thus I have all of them here: https://hub.docker.com/u/sunbake/dashboard/
4. I do know I can set custom environment variables for every EB environment
5. I do know SYMFONY__WHATEVER_NAME can be easily used as application parameters

And now what really troubles me and am asking about **how to do that in a better way?**

6. Inserting sensitive values such as database passwords seems to be a bit fishy - if nothing else, the HTML input filed value can get stored in the browser cache/history
7. Setting environment variables with sensitive data for the whole operating system is much the same - imagine somebody getting any kind of system access and then priting env variables. Even if it was the only possible thing to do, getting a plaintext password that is bad
8. In order to get the environment variables through nginx to the PHP script running via php-fpm, the nginx configuration file has to pass them. In another words if I want to use that approach, I have to have hardcoded parameters (yeah, no values, but read on) in my nginx.conf.

The **8th bullet** is my whole point and problem:

9. Given the 3rd bullet in this text it would mean that I have to rebuild the whole image everytime I want to add a parameter, which can be done, but seems to be an overhead and also means that I can't use the image for multiple applications, which may have different parameters
10. Given the fact that the image and it's source has to be public (I don't plan to pay for the docker hub in this use case), it also discloses parts of how the application works. For instance discloses that if a potential attacker can somehow execute code to list my env variables, he knows for which env variables to look for exactly.

I wish to use the whole bitbucket-docker-dockerhub-eb to automate deployment within multiple environments:

- development on a local host with a specific set of docker images (mailcatcher, local mysql instance, xdebug enabled)
- test environment on AWS EB with no mailcatcher and database in their RDS
- production environment same as the test one, but without xdebug and with some minor optimisation tweaks

Surely there has to be a way how to make this right. I believe I got far, but I am getting some bits wrong. Any hint will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this post totally deserves a TL;DR section

1. You can switch from Dockerhub to Tutom, which offers 10 free private repositories
2. You shouldn't place hard-coded parameters inside docker. this contradicts the whole point of having a docker image
3. You should use EB environment variables to dynamically add/remove env vars at runtime. this will spare you the need to re-build a docker every time (you'll just need to restart the app server from the aws console, which takes only a min)
4. You can encrypt the values of your env vars, and decrypt them in your code. this way they remain a secret.

Comment: #1: Ok, thanks for the tip // #2: Exactly, thus my post // #4: Great idea, thanks! and then #3: yes, the whole post is about my frustration that I was unable to make nginx to take all EB environment variables (and their values) and pass them to the PHP-FPM. I was only able to predefine those variables and then assign values dynamically. Can you elaborate on that a bit, please?

Comment: @JanKlan what is the issue you're facing in #3? Once you define your variables in the elastic beanstalk console (or cli) you can access them in the docker instance. Do you want to access them in the host? (e.g. where nginx is)

Comment: The issue is that for every application I use (or plan to use) there will be a different set of configuration parameters - not values, but parameters. My goal is to have universal docker environment which mounts a dir with Symfony sources and to use this environment with different Symfony applications. Every app will eventually differ not only in param values, but in a set of parameters, which are configurable. So far the only way I know is to hardcode env variable names in the nginx config file. That only works with one Symfony app per set of parameters, therefore one docker container.

Comment: @JanKlan every time you add a docker container to the multi-container env you will need to change your Dockerrun.aws.json file. In that file you also include a list of env variables which are specific to the new docker to be launched.

Comment: yeah, but the problem is with "adding a new container", but "adding new environment variable which Nginx will pass to PHP" and AFAIK that cannot be modified in Dockerrun.aws.json file, but in one of the .conf files of Nginx - am I mistaken?